# Какой объект DTO создать под данный тип json?

Tags: java, jackson

Не могу понять как создать DTO объект, ведь есть динамический ключ, который меняется.

JSON:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "2022-09-01": {
      "isVerified": false
    },
    "2022-09-02": {
      "isVerified": true
    }
  }
}
```

Java class:

```
public class Root {
    public boolean success;
    public Data data;
}

public class Data{

    public ?; **<-- какой тут тип**
}

public ? {
    public boolean isVerified;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких случаях - используйте Map. Обычно подойдёт строка как ключ, но, по идее, можно и заморочиться и, указав как парсить дату, указать Date в качестве ключа:

```
public class Root {
    public boolean success;
    public Data data;
}

public class Data {

    public Map<String, VerifiedState> data;
}

public VerifiedState {
    public boolean isVerified;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, данное решение помогло!

Comment: Если ответ помог - вы можете галочку слева от тела ответа поставить)

Comment: Спасибо, поставил!

Answer (score 0):

Если ключ динамический, то для определения поля `data` следует использовать хэш-таблицу (мапу), где ключом может быть как строка `String`, так и дата `LocalDate`:

```java
public class Root {
    public boolean success;
    public Map<String, Inner> data;
}

public class Inner {
    public boolean isVerified;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, данное решение помогло!